# Binary comparison in refactored code using otool

Tags: c++, c++11, refactoring, binaryfiles, otool

I am refactoring C++ code, removing `using namespace std;` and adding `std::` to strings, vectors, etc. I want the output to be indentical binary-wise, but `cmp` gives diffs even for minimal changes. I resorted to disassembling using `otool` but am encountering weird offsets in addresses.

E.g. with this change

```
diff --git a/src/core_read.cpp b/src/core_read.cpp
@@ -26,7 +26,7 @@ CScript ParseScript(const std::string& s)
{
    CScript result;

-    static map<string, opcodetype> mapOpNames;
+    static std::map<string, opcodetype> mapOpNames;

    if (mapOpNames.empty())
    {
```

`otool -XVt` gives an odd address offset:

```
bench_bitcoin.s:
8c8
<       movq    0x392f7b(%rip), %rbx ## literal pool symbol address: ___stack_chk_guard
---
>       movq    0x392f8b(%rip), %rbx ## literal pool symbol address: ___stack_chk_guard
19c19
<       jne     0x100003fa9
---
>       jne     0x100003f99
25c25
<       callq   0x100229c44 ## symbol stub for: ___stack_chk_fail
---
>       callq   0x100229c34 ## symbol stub for: ___stack_chk_fail
33c33
<       movq    0x392f2b(%rip), %rbx ## literal pool symbol address: ___stack_chk_guard
---
>       movq    0x392f3b(%rip), %rbx ## literal pool symbol address: ___stack_chk_guard
[…]
```

It literally shifts all addies +/-0x10. Is there a way to prevent this? Why is it happening in the first place?

Reverting the above change and recompiling gives the original addresses, so it's probably not a matter of "randomness" in address selection.

Comment: Why would you want to depend on such things ?

Comment: The diff is rather large, and I would like to prove that the resulting binary is exactly the same as before the added `std::`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case (bitcoin core), W.J. van der Laan has apparently written a tool for this very purpose. It may be inspirational in case others want something similar. (MIT licensed)

https://github.com/laanwj/bitcoin-maintainer-tools